# Why go I get error 1004 when calling a macro from Word doc, but not from Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, automation

In a Word file, I have a macro that opens an Excel file and calls for a macro in that file. (I'm using VBA.)  This is the simple code from Word:

```
Set oExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oWorkbook = oExcelApp.workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\Eddy\Mina dokument\Insajt\Arbeten\Prido\Affärssystem\www\modules\mod_order\eco.xls")
oExcelApp.Visible = True
oExcelApp.Run "'ECO.xls'!Ritning"
```

The Excel file opens and the macro runs, but then I get an error prompt (translated from Swedish.):

*Run-time error '1004 '
 PrintArea property can not be entered for the class, PageSetup*

If I choose Debug mode, this line is highlighted:

```
.PrintArea = "$A$1:$O$49;$Q$1:$AE$49;$Q$50:$AE$97;$AG$50:$AU$97"
```

The whole section of code is this:

```
   If Sheets("Beräkningar").Cells(6, 2) = "4V" Then 
        With Sheets("Ritn").PageSetup 
            .PrintArea = "$A$1:$O$49;$Q$1:$AE$49;$Q$50:$AE$97;$AG$50:$AU$97" 
            .Zoom = 85 
        End With 
        Sheets("Ritn").PrintOut 
    End If
```

Now to the really strange thing. If I abort the call for the macro in the Excel file and just manually call the same macro, it works like a charm.  Same if I manually open the Excel file and start the macro, then everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a comma delimited list instead of semicolon

```
.PrintArea = "$A$1:$O$49,$Q$1:$AE$49,$Q$50:$AE$97,$AG$50:$AU$97"
```

Comment: Worth a try, but the separator looks appropriate for the locale. (And works when called directly, according to the OP).